# 2 jQuery Timepickers -- How to Distinguish (jquery.timepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I'm using `jQuery.timepicker` (not sure how widely this plugin is used -- it was created by Jon Thornton, Git: https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker and Sample Page: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

I have 2 timepickers that I've created, StartTime and EndTime, which populate dropdowns with 5-min.-interval choices from 00:00 to 23:59.

e.g.,

```
$('#startTime').timepicker({
      'minTime': '12:00am',
      'maxTime': '11:59pm',
      'step': '5', 
      'showDuration': 'false'
});     

$('#endTime').timepicker({
      'minTime': '12:00am',
      'maxTime': '11:59pm',
      'step': '5', 
      'showDuration': 'false'
});
```

But in the final HTML this inserts identical supporting DIVs that pop up when clicking on an input field. As far as I can tell they're not distinguished by position, ID, or class.

```
<div class="ui-timepicker-wrapper" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; top: 230.233px; left: 345.667px; display: none;">
    <ul class="ui-timepicker-list">
       <li>12:00am</li>
       <li>12:05am</li>
       ...
</ul></div>
```

for both. Is there any way I could distinguish them? I need to delete some entries from #2 upon selection in #1. The following doesn't work because it deletes from the wrong list. In this example, I need to delete from #2's list the time selected in #1.

```
$('#endTime').on('showTimepicker', function() {
    var current = $('.ui-timepicker-list li').filter(function() { // Exact match necessary
        return $(this)[0].childNodes[0].textContent == $('#startTime').val();
    });
    if (current.length) {
        $(current).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the timepicker, you can use the `className:` option to specify a class to give the HTML element containing the dropdown. So give the two timepickers different classes:

```
$('#startTime').timepicker({
      className: 'startTime',
      'minTime': '12:00am',
      'maxTime': '11:59pm',
      'step': '5', 
      'showDuration': 'false'
});     

$('#endTime').timepicker({
      className: 'endTime',
      'minTime': '12:00am',
      'maxTime': '11:59pm',
      'step': '5', 
      'showDuration': 'false'
});

$('#endTime').on('showTimepicker', function() {
    var current = $('.endTime li').filter(function() { // Exact match necessary
        return $(this).text() == $('#startTime').val();
    });
    current.remove();
});
```

You also don't need that verbose code to get the text of the list item, just use `$(this).text()`. And there's no need to check the length of `current`; if it's empty, `remove()` won't do anything (almost all jQuery methods have no problem processing empty collections).

Comment: But the problem is the .ul-timepicker-list list isn't directly next to the #endTime. We can't make assumptions about position -- the two DIV's are both at the end and separated from the fields they support.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and found a clean method.